# I'm having trouble writing a cursor/loop. I'm not sure why it's not working

Tags: plsql

My code is here. I keep getting errors for the select statement. I've already created a waitlist table and a sequence. I inserted values into waitlist, however; I had to get the sname from the students table since waitlist does not have sname in the table. I'm trying to display RankingSid, Snum, sname, time(such as 1 pm or 2 pm).

```
   create or replace procedure getWaiting(
p_callnum waitlist.callnum%type) as

cursor cwaiting is
    select RankingSid, waitlist.snum, students.sname, to_char(time, 'hh AM')time
    from waitlist, students
    where p_callnum=callnum
    and waitlist.snum=students.snum;

begin
For EachStudent in cwaiting loop
insert into TestTable values (EachStudent.RankingSid, Eachstudent.snum, EachStudent.sname, EachStudent.time);

dbms_output.put_line(eachstudent.rankingsid || eachstudent.snum || eachstudent.sname, eachstudent.time);
end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be a select or insert as in the way your insert statement has been written? What is the error that you're getting?

Comment: well I keep getting select or insert errors. I fixed the code but if I use insert into TestTable, I get statement ignored and Table or View does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of syntax errors in your code, the biggest being your insert statement you need to reference your cursor variable for the insert in the same way that you did for the dbms_output.  I do not have your table definitions to test the code but the below should be pretty close to what you need.

```
    create or replace procedure getWaiting(
p_callnum waitlist.callnum%type) as

cursor cwaiting is
    select RankingSid, waitlist.snum, students.sname, to_char(time, 'hh AM')time
    from waitlist, students
    where p_callnum=callnum
    and waitlist.snum=students.snum;

begin
For EachStudent in cwaiting loop
insert into TestTable values (EachStudent.RankingSid, Eachstudent.snum, EachStudent.sname, EachStudent.time);

dbms_output.put_line(eachstudent.rankingsid || eachstudent.snum || eachstudent.sname || eachstudent.time);
end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: So I did something similar. Do I have to create the testtable before running this procedure though? I keep getting table or view does not exist.

Comment: @JeffreyPaz yes, if you are going to insert into a table you will need to create it first.  If you don't need the test table just take the insert out altogether and leave the dbms_output there.  I had made the assumption that the TestTable was already created.

Comment: ah I see. I probably should create a testable. I'm going to test it with just the dbms output but I got it to work doing it a different way. I just want to learn to use cursor in different ways.

Comment: I was overthinking it. Thanks it worked without the insert. Idk why I thought I had to insert into a new table. It always takes me some time away to realize what I did wrong when I come back to it.

Comment: I created the TestTable, how do I display the table when I execute the procedure though? I want it to show the TestTable. I got everything else fixed, I just forgot how to use a select statement inside a procedure

Answer (score 0):

I did it another way and would like to know how to change it..insert table wasn't working the other way. I was wondering if i'd have to create instead of inserting

```
create or replace procedure getWaiting(
    p_callnum waitlist.callnum%type) as




begin
    For eachRec in (select waitlist.rankingsid, students.snum, students.sname, to_char(time, 'hh:mi:ss AM') RequestedTime
        from students, waitlist
        where p_callnum=callnum
        and students.snum=waitlist.snum
        order by rankingsid)

    Loop
        dbms_output.put_line('Rank Number '|| eachRec.rankingsid ||' Student Name ' ||eachRec.sname ||' Student Number ' || eachRec.snum ||' Wait List Date ' || eachRec.RequestedTime);

    end Loop;


end;
/
```